# Gitlab automated changelog creation

Tags: ruby, gitlab, changelog

I was wondering how the CHANGELOG.md overall file is created.
I've seen this site https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/development/changelog-manager.html but I don't know where to find changelog_manager.rb and how to correctly call it, that i get a overall CHANGELOG.md out of multiple changelog entries (https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/development/changelog.html).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the repo at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/-/tree/master.

The referenced script name `scripts/changelog_manager.rb` no longer exists in this repo, going by the content and history I'd say it was refactored/reorganized and you'd use `bin/changelog` today.

Comment: Yes right, but this script is only for creating the single changelogs (coming from each developer and each development task), but these changelogs are "compiled together" into one CHANGELOG.md, if, for example, the sinlge changes are merged into a master branch.

Comment: If you want functionality that the referenced script doesn't provide you need to implement that on your own.